# udp socket causing winerror 10054 using python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp

I've been attempting to use datagram socket via python, but I keep getting  [Errno 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host, that shouldn't occur while using udp

```
import socket
b = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,     socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
b.bind(('127.0.0.1',12000))
b.sendto(b"check", ('127.0.0.1', 3943))
b.recv(48)
```

it catches an exception while calling recv, if I remove sendto everything works fine. Why? It is not tcp so there shall not be such error

Comment: I think this happens in UDP if the remote host sends ICMP Port Unreachable. So it means that there's nothing listening on port 3943.

Comment: @Barmar is correct. Over a LAN you can only get this behaviour with a connected socket, but within localhost it seems to work differently.